# how to get email of authenticated user in angularjs using satellizer

Tags: angularjs, authentication, satellizer

I am creating a webapp in angularJs, and using [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) for authentication. I am able to use to authenticate using google, but I couldn't figure out how to get email id of authenticated user somewhere in my UI code. I couldn't found any function also to get email id in  [documentation](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer).

Comment: You should point scope which you want to get. for example: `$authProvider.google({
  url: '/auth/google',
  scope: ['profile', 'email']});`

Comment: And so, you can get response from the service `$auth.login(user)
  .then(function(response) {
    // Could be your user returned from the server.
  })`

Comment: I think you have that response because you didn't change server side. I suggest you should return user from auth/google. Or you can invoke user/me immideately. It provides current user. https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js

Comment: See my ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740186/how-to-get-email-from-facebook-through-guzzle-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was, hit googleapis using the access_token satelizer save in your browser's local memory, which returns user info, Following is the service for your reference:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('Google', ['$resource', '$auth', Google]);

function Google($resource, $auth) {
    return $resource("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=" + $auth.getToken(), {}, {})
}
```

You can just do following to get email id of logged in user:

```
var googleResponse = Google.get({}, function () {
    var email = googleResponse.email;
});
```